# UWP Application : Map Route API (MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync) does not respond and even no way to refresh or cancel a request

Tags: c#, uwp, maproute

I am trying to draw a route on Map Control in UWP application for desktops for specific locations:

Start: { Latitude = 33.8917742, Longitude = -87.5261236 }
End: { Latitude = 32.318231, Longitude = -86.902298 }

Caller API:
MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(startPoint, endPoint)

Issue: after I call, it never respond , It does not accept cancelation token, then I have tried to cancel manually with different approach but does not work. It seems initiator never canceled.

[See here locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDzsM.jpg)
Please let me know in case required more details.

Code Snap shot

var startPoint = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 33.8917742, Longitude = -87.5261236 });
var endPoint = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 32.318231, Longitude = -86.902298 });
var routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(startPoint, endPoint);

```
            if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
            {
                MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);
                viewOfRoute.RouteColor = Colors.Orange;
                viewOfRoute.OutlineColor = Colors.Red;
                myMap.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);
            }
```

Please find Video and Sample Code here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_hQtOxLV8YCO-AwzKGLKIGXCfJX1hL8R?usp=sharing

Device Information:
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer Hewlett-Packard
System Model    HP EliteBook 840 G2
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2601 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Hewlett-Packard M71 Ver. 01.28, 4/18/2019
SMBIOS Version  2.7
Embedded Controller Version 150.91
BIOS Mode   Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Hewlett-Packard
BaseBoard Product   2216
BaseBoard Version   KBC Version 96.5B
Platform Role   Mobile
Locale  United States
Time Zone   India Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 12.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   11.9 GB
Available Physical Memory   2.38 GB
Total Virtual Memory    17.1 GB
Available Virtual Memory    4.07 GB
Page File Space 5.23 GB
Kernel DMA Protection   Off

**

> [Issue Resolved]: Today[1 Oct 2020] I have restart my system and tried again and issue
> was fixed, My code is working, Still not sure why it was happened.

I had posted same issue here and someone suggested to reinstall Map app. Then I tried restart.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/112943/uwp-application-map-route-api-maproutefindergetdri.html

**

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue. How do you use the method? It will be good if you could share the code snippet. Another thing is that if put a breakpoint under the next line of this method when you are debugging, will it stop there?

Comment: In my test, this API could return the MapRouteFinderResult correctly and display it on the map. It is unclear about the behavior you mentioned. You could provide a screenshot to describe the behavior you meet.

Comment: yes it works for other locations, it is causing issue when selecting long distance location I have added locations and code sample.

Comment: I'm using the location you give. it works correctly

Comment: One more question, have you provide the MapServiceToken to the map?

Comment: yes i have added map key

Comment: There is no issue with the code, I could see the Orange route in the map

Comment: When you said `it never respond`, could you please share a screenshot when running this method to tell us what happened after the method is called?

Comment: Please find Video and Sample Code here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_hQtOxLV8YCO-AwzKGLKIGXCfJX1hL8R?usp=sharing

Comment: I have removed MapKey in Sample

Comment: Thank you for the sample. The result I got is still correct. When the app running on my side, the route will show after I click the route button. It takes less than 1 second. It looks like the request does not get the response data from the bing map service. The code is correct. Do the functions work correctly when you are using the bing map site from the browser?

Comment: I have also used Performance Profiler with Network Trace and driving rest API having success response. Please find attached file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n8x-3Iv5ZErltvAvnoet3S7dyAYcPDhR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You could ask this issue in [Bing Map forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=bingmaps) The support team is actively answering bing map questions there.

Comment: Bing map site from the browser working correctly but when I am using Map app same issue is there.

Comment: Please could try to test it in a different device in a different network. I suspect this might be related to some local network setting or group policy.

Comment: And please ask this in the [Bing Map forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=bingmaps) so you could get more help

Comment: Thanks @RoyLi-MSFT , My team tested same scenario on multiple machine with different network but same issue is there can you please provide  your sys configuration like , OS, CPU , RAM so that we can test on same, As you suggested I have posted query on Bing Forum   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c32caba-c49d-4870-874e-c80c48c6de22/uwp-application-map-route-api-maproutefindergetdrivingrouteasync-does-not-respond-and-even-no?forum=bingmaps

Comment: I'm testing this in build 19041.624. If your team are all in the same organization network, then the issue could be related to the network policy

Comment: Its COVID-19 everyone working from Home, personal network is being used, I will update my system current Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362.

Comment: After restart my system, I was able to draw route.

Comment: Are your teammates using the same OS version as you before?